# How can I view my site's PageRank?

Tags: google, pagerank

There is some articles on the web saying that Google Page Rank isn't dead and it's just hidden from public by google ,I found some websites for checking my site page rank, But the results was entirely different , So how can I check my page rank?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So how can I check my page rank?

**You can't** -- not anymore, at least.

Google hasn't provided/updated that data in years.

There are 3rd party tools that attempt to fill in the gap, but as you mentioned, they can vary wildly.